# powershell auto shutdown script using ScheduledJob

Tags: powershell

[Update]:
Finally figured it out thanks to Hey, Scripting Guy blog (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/16/troubleshooting-powershell-scheduled-jobs/), updated original code with working one. [/Update]

I would like to write a powershell script that would add a scheduled job for me on Windows 10 1706.
The job should:

1. Stop-Computer (localhost)
2. Run everyday except weekends @ a specific time.
3. Wake PC if its asleep to run the script block.
4. Ignore if user is on "lock screen" and shutdown anyway.

I wrote a few lines using the built-in help in PS, that would accomplish some of this:

```
$T = New-JobTrigger -DaysOfWeek 1,2,3,4,5 -At 18:40 -Weekly

$O = New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated -WakeToRun -IdleDuration 00:00:00 -IdleTimeout 00:00:00

Register-ScheduledJob -Name "AutoShutdown" -ScriptBlock {Stop-Computer -Force} -Trigger $T -ScheduledJobOption $O -Credential Admin_username
```

Running these lines adds the job, but it simply doesn't do anything.

I'd love to make a script that later can be used in a domain, however currently I only need to use them on a few local machines to ease administration.

Thanks for the aid in advance!

*Update:
Finally figured it out thanks to Hey, Scripting Guy blog (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/16/troubleshooting-powershell-scheduled-jobs/), updated original code with working one.

Comment: `-ComputerName localhost` isn't needed, if the param is not specified the commands runs locally.

Comment: Hey there! I've also tried ommiting the -computername parameter, but the command doesn't run on the machines anyway. It does run the command if I just type what is in the script block either way, so I think the issue is with the scheduled-job setup.

Comment: Anyone got any idea why the job doesn't run? Maybe if I could debug the scheduled-job somehow? Thanks in advance!